# python 3.2 tkinter, text in radio button is not display

Tags: python, text, tkinter, radio-button

So I have been play around with python 3.2 tkinter. 
Today just found the text in radio button is not display next to the button, it only show "0".
Also, when I have .pack() at the end of a radio button statement, it shows error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'. It is so weird, is that because of they changed in new version. Do I need to import some thing else? Thanks

```
from tkinter import*

class Name:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self._var = IntVar()
        self._fullRadio = Radiobutton(frame, text="yes", textvariable=self._var, value=1)
        self._fullRadio.grid(row=2, column=0)#.pack()

        self._partRadio = Radiobutton(frame, text="no", textvariable=self._var, value=2)
        self._partRadio.grid(row=3)#.pack()

        self._notRadio = Radiobutton(frame, text="not both", textvariable=self._var, value=3)
        self._notRadio.grid(row=4)#.pack()

root = Tk()
application = Name(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the parameter `variable`, not `textvariable`:

```
from tkinter import*
class Name:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid() # changed from frame.pack()

        self._var = IntVar()
        self._fullRadio = Radiobutton(frame, text="yes", variable=self._var, value=1)
        self._fullRadio.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self._partRadio = Radiobutton(frame, text="no", variable=self._var, value=2)
        self._partRadio.grid(row=3)

        self._notRadio = Radiobutton(frame, text="not both", variable=self._var, value=3)
        self._notRadio.grid(row=4)

root = Tk()
application = Name(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also, as a rule of thumb, it's not preferred to mix `.grid()` and `.pack()` in the same frame.

As for your second question: `.grid()` is another layout manager. just doing `self._fullRadio.grid(row=2, column=0)` already sets the layout; you do not need to use `.pack()` in addition to `.grid()` (on the same object).

You get the error that a `NoneType` object does not have the method `.pack()` because `self._fullRadio.grid(row=2, column=0)` returns `None` (it is a method call). Stick to either `grid` or `pack`, but not both at the same time.

Comment: You can mix  pack and grid in the same app, just not in the same container (ie: not in the same frame). This is because each looks for changes in widget size and (potentially) readjusts the size of all of the windows it manages when one changes size. What happens, then, is that grid changes the size of some widgets according to its rules, pack notices the changes and thus changes the size of other widgets according to _its_ rules. Grid notices the changes, etc in omne tempus. However, using both grid and pack in the same _application_ is something all experienced Tkinter coders do.